# React: updating a property from another state based on the onchange event value

Tags: reactjs, jsx

![Trying to update fee based on the amount value entered]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CfYTE.png

Comment: Please edit your question and provide your code sample so others can help

Comment: There is code sample in the link above.

Answer (score 0):

Your state is called `amount` that contains an object with a key called `amount`

`const [amount, setAmount] = setState({amount: ""})`

However, in your JSX you're passing the entire state instead of the key.
`value={amount}` should be `value={amount.amount}` and likewise in the `<h2>` tag

Comment: Thanks for the help! But the amount is showing, the fee is not responsive to the number im typing. as you can see in the img when i type 5 it should set the fee to 1, but it makes it 0.50, and when i delete the input it sets it to 1. basically what i want to do in my Onchange fee function is taking whatever the e.target.value parse it as int since its a string then do a if else to setFee.

Comment: @bryceio Gotcha, can you paste your component in codepen or codesandbox and share the link?